# NULL variable value from a input insert in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

```
    $imageencode = $this->curl->simple_get($reqUrl);

    $data = array(  
            'image' => $this->input->post('imageencode')
            );
    $this->db->insert('images_from_balance',$data);
```

In my $imageencode variable I will get a binary code for a image, and I want to insert that in a mysql table called images_from_balance on a blob type field named image.

I think that is a problem with the format of my array, that is from html form inputs, but I don't know how to make that array to insert my variable.

This is my error that I get:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1048
>
> Column 'image' cannot be null
>
> INSERT INTO `images_from_balance` (`image`) VALUES (NULL)

Comment: see you database structure there is you have not allow null value in this filed

Comment: @Tatu can you update question with what $imageencode returns??

Comment: @Gulshan I see that you deleted your post, $imageencode is returning a long binary code corresponding to a image.

Comment: @TatuBogdan is value comes in array??

Comment: No, its just like a long string I can also base64 encode it.

Comment: @TatuBogdan csn you add that output in your question??

Comment: @TatuBogdan then you can use my code.for it..but check your db column..it's type should be longtext

Comment: I will right now, also @krishnpatel it's already with no NULL

Comment: this why it is given error you have not allowed null value in this column. allow null value. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update

```
$imageencode = $this->curl->simple_get($reqUrl);
$data = array( 'image' => $this->input->post('imageencode'));
```

With:

```
$imageencode = $this->curl->simple_get($reqUrl);
$data = array( 'image' => $imageencode);
```

Comment: This work! Was a syntax problem from my side, this is propper way: $data = array( 'image' => $imageencode);